# Function that loops through the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make Apps Script macro that will do following:

- Check if checkmark (cell value = TRUE/FALSE) is ticked in column A
- If it's ticked, increase value of cell in column H
- Repeat until reached the last row.

After a little bit of digging around in documentation, I came up with this, and from my understanding it should be working, but since I'm asking a question here, it obviously does not. Script does get executed without errors, but it changes nothing on the sheet.

```
function increment() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var EndRow = ss.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 2; i <= EndRow; i++) {
      var Cell = ss.getRange(i,8);
      var CheckmarkCell = ss.getRange(i,1);
      if (CheckmarkCell.getValue() == 'TRUE') {
          ss.Cell.setValue(ss.Cell.getValue() + 1);
      }
  }
}
```

Anyone has any idea, what's wrong here?

Comment: Change 'ss.Cell ' to 'Cell'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps?

```js
function increMentWhenTrue() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange().offset(2, 0)
  const values = sh.getValues().map(r => {
    r[7] = (r[0]) ? (r[7]) ? r[7]+1 : 1 : r[7];
    return r; 
    })
  sh.setValues(values);
}
```

Change the sheet name in the first line to suit your requirements.

Same code with if-else statements

```js
function increMentWhenTrue() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Blad1').getDataRange().offset(2, 0)
  const values = sh.getValues().map(r => {
    if (r[0]) {
      if (r[7]) {
        r[7] = r[7] + 1;
      } else {
        r[7] = 1;
      }
    } else {
      r[7] = r[7];
    }

    return r;
  })
  sh.setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Got a question though, could you explain this a bit, so I get to use it in the  future. While I know that using combined complex if statements (like you did, with (? : : ) thing) makes code smaller, it makes it hard to read the code

Comment: Well, instead of getting the value per cell (inside a loop) which is never a good idea the script gets all the values of the datarange in one call then processes all the data internally. A [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is used to determine if r[0] evaluates to 'true'.

Comment: If it does, a second ternary is used to check if there is a value in column H of that row. If not, the cell will have a '1'; if there is a value the value is incremented by 1.  If r[0] (column A) is not true, the value in column A is untouched.  Finally all the data is written back to the sheet in a single .setValues() call. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: I edited my post so that it now shows the same code with if-else statements instead of ternary operators.

Comment: Unfolding the brackets helped a lot in understanding what's going on, cheers.